# How to depend on a common crossProject

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I am defining multiple JVM/JS cross projects. Each one contains some common JVM/JS scala code that I want to extract into a general common project that each project can depend on. Could someone recommend me the best way to define my build.scala files for the general and dependent projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up arriving at the solution below.

```
lazy val common = crossProject.in(file(".")).
    settings(
    ).
    jvmSettings(
    ).
    jsSettings(
    )

lazy val commonJVM = common.jvm
lazy val commonJS = common.js
```

...

```
lazy val p1 = crossProject.in(file(".")).
    settings(
    ).
    jvmSettings(
    ).
    jsSettings(
    ).
    jvmConfigure(_.dependsOn(ProjectRef(uri("../common"), "commonJVM"))).
    jsConfigure(_.dependsOn(ProjectRef(uri("../common"), "commonJS")))

lazy val p1JVM = p1.jvm.
    settings(...

lazy val p1JS = p1.js.
    settings(...
```

Answer (score 3):

`CrossProject` supports the normal `dependsOn` operation you are used to. So you can:

```
// call to settings needed so for an implicit conversion to kick in
lazy val common = crossProject.settings() 
lazy val p1 = crossProject.dependsOn(common)
lazy val p2 = crossProject.dependsOn(common)

lazy val commonJVM = common.jvm
lazy val commonJS = common.js
lazy val p1JVM = p1.jvm
lazy val p1JS = p1.js
lazy val p2JVM = p2.jvm
lazy val p2JS = p2.js
```

There is a [full example](https://github.com/scala-js/scalajs-cross-compile-example) on GitHub.

Comment: When I do this I get an assertion failed: "Directory ...common/js is not contained in build root ...p1". The common project should to be totally independent of the other projects so it shouldn't be a sub-project of any of the other ones.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (updated the answer to contain the exact build file I am using). I'm using sbt 0.13.7. Could you give me a gist of what you are using? Also could you give me the output of `sbt> projects`?

Comment: I ended up with the solution below. Not sure exactly how I got there to be honest! Using sbt 13.8 and scala.js 0.6.5

Answer (score 1):

You can create [Multi-project builds](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html)

Let's say you have project structure like this;

```
root        
    project/Build.scala
    project1
        src/
        project1.sbt
    project2
        src/
        project2.sbt
    projectN
        src/
        projectN.sbt
```

You can easily define dependencies in `Build.scala`

```
lazy val root = Project(id = "Main-Project",
    base = file(".")) aggregate(project1, project2,..)

lazy val project2 = Project(id = "project2",
    base = file("project1")).dependsOn(project1)

...
```